# Поиск библиотек Python для комплексной обработки текста: исправление ошибок и удаление лишних символов

Tags: python, текст, nlp

Я работаю над проектом по обработке текстовых данных с целью исправления грамматических и орфографических ошибок, а также удаления лишних символов и пробелов. Интересуюсь подходящими инструментами и библиотеками Python для решения этих задач. Важно, что мне нужно решение, работающее локально, без обращения к API внешних сервисов, так как проект предполагает полную офлайн-работу.

Мне важно, чтобы инструмент позволял легко настраивать правила обработки текста и мог интегрироваться в существующий проект без необходимости значительных инвестиций в вычислительные мощности.

Примеры исправлений, которые я хочу автоматизировать:

- Грамматические ошибки (например, "Я не знает куда он пошёл." должно стать "Я не знаю, куда он пошёл.").
- Орфографические ошибки (например, "сдэлать" на "сделать").
- Удаление лишних символов и пробелов (например, "При вет! К ак дел а?" на "Привет! Как дела?").

Я рассмотрел несколько вариантов, но они либо были слишком базовы для моих нужд, либо требовательны к ресурсам. Буду благодарен за любые советы по подходящим библиотекам, инструментам или открытым проектам на Python, которые могли бы помочь в решении этих задач.